# Using cv2 to import coordinates of an image into Python. Coordinates, do not return image correctly when plotted after import

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, image, opencv

I have imported the image, [image: Cross in black] , and then assigned the corners to x and y coordinates:

```
# Import image and define coords.
def image_read():
img = cv2.imread('initlayout.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = np.float32(gray)

corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray, 100, 0.01, 10)
corners = np.int0(corners)
x = []
y = []
for corner in corners:
    a, b = corner.ravel()
    x.append(a)
    y.append(b)
No_vertices = len(x)
return x, y, No_vertices
```

But now when I plot the shape with the following code:

```
# Plot the polygon.
def plotter(x, y):
x.append(x[0])
y.append(y[0])
figure()
plot(x, y)
show()
```

I see that the coordinates are not in the right order because the resulting image is, [image: Messed up cross] .

Any advice on how to get the cross to show up similar to this, but with the coordinates from the original image?
[image: Correct Cross]

Answer (score 0):

The [contract for goodFeaturesToTrack](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#goodfeaturestotrack) makes no assurances on feature order. It appears to be working down from the top of the image, scanning left to right, which is an entirely sensible thing to do, though it make it a poor fit for your needs.

Given what you desire, you might have better luck with [findContours](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours). There's an approacheable walkthrough of `findContours` [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/04/21/building-pokedex-python-finding-game-boy-screen-step-4-6/).